# How to continue editing project with git / heroku?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm following [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) which initializes a project from scratch, and goes on. But I couldn't find how to continue editing. I mean, I wrote some of the code, uploaded it with `git push heroku master`, then turn the computer off, and tomorrow I open it again, and continue editing the source files, and I want to update the project. Is just `cd projectdir` and `git push heroku master` enough?

Or what else should I do to continue editing a python (django) project with heroku?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably read through the [Git tutorial](http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial) or [the one on Github](https://try.github.io/) to learn the basics of repo handling, editing, commits, pushing, and pulling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should do it exactly as you did today. Mind you, you must've committed your changes before you did

```
git push heroku master
```

Quite possibly, what you did was this

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "my django app"
$ git push heroku master
```

Tomorrow, you'll do it exactly in the same way. Please note that first load of your website tomorrow might be slow, this is due to the way heroku puts free (non paid) apps to sleep.
As pointed by @MattDMo, you may want to have a look at git tutorial to perform more advanced source management.

Comment: Thanks!. So do I have to initialize any of the programs? For example, the tutorial also says `heroku login`, is that necessary?

Comment: Yes, indeed, you'll also need to login.